# Convert Canvas to ImageSource

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

im attempting to convert a canvas to a image source for use as an OpacityMask, I want to save it into memory rather than save it as a file, i'm having trouble though. Below is my code, I think i'm going about it wrong!

Really, I need to get the image information as a `Base64String`, so somewhere between that I need to convert the `RenderTargetBitmap`!

```
public BitmapSource ExportToPng(Uri path, Canvas surface)
{
    BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    System.IO.MemoryStream myStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

    // Save current canvas transform
    Transform transform = surface.LayoutTransform;
    // reset current transform (in case it is scaled or rotated)
    surface.LayoutTransform = null;

    // Get the size of canvas
    System.Windows.Size size = new System.Windows.Size(surface.ActualWidth, surface.ActualHeight);
    // Measure and arrange the surface
    // VERY IMPORTANT
    surface.Measure(size);
    surface.Arrange(new Rect(size));

    // Create a render bitmap and push the surface to it
    RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap =
        new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)size.Width,
        (int)size.Height,
        96d,
        96d,
        PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    renderBitmap.Render(surface);

    // push the rendered bitmap to it
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));
    // save the data to the stream
    encoder.Save(myStream);

    // Restore previously saved layout
    surface.LayoutTransform = transform;

    var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(myStream);
    var myStr = sr.ReadToEnd();
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(myStr);

    // Save to memory
    /*Bitmap pg = new Bitmap("525, 350");
    Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(pg);

    gr.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255)), 0, 0, (float)size.Width, (float)size.Height);
    gr.DrawImage(System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(myStream), 0, 0);*/



    return BitmapFromBase64(myStr);
}
public static BitmapSource BitmapFromBase64(string base64String)
{
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

    using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        return BitmapFrame.Create(stream,
            BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Just found another possible way, however this creates a DrawingVisual, I need to convert that to a ImageBrush

C#

```
// Create a DrawingVisual that contains a rectangle.
        private DrawingVisual CreateDrawingVisualRectangle(List<Rectangle> rectangles)
        {
            DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();

            // Retrieve the DrawingContext in order to create new drawing content.
            DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();

            // Create a rectangle and draw it in the DrawingContext.
            foreach(Rectangle x in rectangles)
            {
                Rect rect = new Rect(new System.Windows.Point(x.X, x.Y), new System.Windows.Size(x.Width, x.Height));
                drawingContext.DrawRectangle(System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black, (System.Windows.Media.Pen)null, rect);
            }

        // Persist the drawing content.
        drawingContext.Close();

        return drawingVisual;
    }
```

Comment: UIElement takes any Brush as OpacityMask. Why not use a VisualBrush? Canvas c = new Canvas();
element.OpacityMask = new VisualBrush( c );

Comment: Ah, didn't think I could use a VisualBrush there, thanks!

Comment: This makes EVERYTHING so much simplier, I thought I had to convert the canvas to some form of image, but being able to use it directly is MUCH better

Comment: Make that your answer please @SnowballTwo

Comment: Whilst your at it you should add that answer to this other similar question too:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34325221/use-canvas-to-mask-background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UIElement takes any Brush as OpacityMask. You can simply create a VisualBrush from you Canvas, since the base class of every UIElement is SWM.Visual.

```
Canvas c = new Canvas();
element.OpacityMask = new VisualBrush( c );
```

Regards, Snowball